# Is CallKit Sufficient

Tags: ios, swift, callkit

I am new to ios development. I am trying to build a voip app and I was wondering, is callkit all I need? or I need to integrate it with an already built voip app, using for example WebRTC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you might have guessed, CallKit alone is not sufficient.
CallKit only provides the **system-calling UI**, and you need to develop the backend system for yourself. (Of course, you can use Web RTC instead of VoIP.)

> Use CallKit to integrate your calling services with other call-related apps on the system. CallKit provides the calling interface, and you handle the back-end communication with your VoIP service.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/callkit

Comment: I didn't know that web rtc differs from voip, I am gonna read more about the differences

Comment: oh by the way, I am developing using flutter, and I read that I can use web rtc even for mobile apps, is that correct?

Comment: Yes, you can use WebRTC in Mobile App as well.
I have not develop any flutter app, but I have used the following libraries in Swift.
https://docs.agora.io/en/Voice/landing-page?platform=iOS

Comment: There is also an SDK for Flutter.
https://docs.agora.io/en/Voice/landing-page?platform=Flutter